# How to display a two dimensional array as a hierarchy table in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to display the below two dimensional array as a hierarchy relationship Java. Is there an easy way to display this as a hierarchy code.

```
Parent     Child
   N01        null
   N02        null
   N03        null
   N04        R1 
   N04        R2 
   N04        R3 
   R1         R4 
   R10        R13 
   R11        R14 
   R12        R15 
   R13        R16 
   R14        R17 
   R15        R18 
   R16        R19 
   R17        R20 
   R18        R21 
   R19        R22 
   R2         R5 
   R20        R23 
   R21        R24 
   R22        R25 
   R23        R26 
   R24        R27 
   R25        R28 
   R26        null
   R27        null
   R28        null
   R3         R6 
   R4         R7 
   R5         R8 
   R6         R9 
   R7         R10 
   R8         R11 
   R9         R12
```

I would like to display a tree structure like the below.

N04
|
  ----> R1
       |
            -----> R4
                |------->  R7
            .
            .
            . and so on...

Comment: How are you displaying it? Console? Text-file? GUI? Please be more specific. I suggest using a nested forloop to loop. The outter loop loops thrpugh the first index, choosing which dimension to loop through, then the inner loop to loop through each index of each dimension. This gives you control on when to create a space, tab, or new line if needed.

Comment: Hi i would like to display a tree structure like the below 
N04      
|
----> R1    
       |
        -----> R4   
  |------->  R7  
   .
   .
   .

Comment: What code have you written so far? What problems are you having with it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I was able to achive this as mentioned in the below comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class for `Node`, with a set of `children`, which are nodes as well, store the root `Node`(s). Implement method for insertion. Then implement the following algorithm:

1. Find the elements, having `null` as `parent`, store them as root nodes.
2. When a `Node` is created, find all its `children` and create them as `children`.

(Note, that whenever you add a child a `Node` was created).

Implement the display method, which traverses the tree in depth-first fashion and display each element as you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used the two arraylist one for parent and one for child and one more Hashtable with key as parent and value as list with all the childs and created the tree structure using the recursive function. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: @Valan,I happy I could help. If my answer was helpful, then you may consider accepting it so future visitors will be helped as well.